# My code produces -nan on changing data type from float to double

Tags: c, compiler-errors, nan

```
int main(void) {
    float a;
    scanf("%f", &a);
    double c = sqrt(a);
    printf("%f", c);
    return 0;
}
```

A float variable results in correct output.
However, on changing the data type to double result is NaN.

Comment: Which compiler and OS are you using?

Comment: You should use the format specifier `%lf' while taking a double input.  You are possibly not doing so, which results in NaN.

Comment: "My code produces -nan" Show code that reproduces the problem without requiring a modification.

Comment: @CodingBatman, but OP is using a `float`, not a `double`.

Comment: @AlterMann, but below the post, the OP says *on changing the data type to double*

Comment: @CodingBatman, oops, ok, I didn't see that.

Comment: It might also be compiler problem. Some compilers (say turbo c++) use a floating point emulator.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the format specifier `%lf` for taking in a `double`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(void) {
    double a;
    scanf("%lf", &a);
    double c = sqrt(a);
    printf("%lf", c); //printf("%f", c) also works perfectly.
    return 0;
}
```

Since you are possibly using just `%f`, you get NaN.

Comment: variable `a` should be of a float type(as mentioned in question)

Comment: @AnishSharma, read the line below the question - *on changing the datatype to double* - although I agree that the OP should have posted that code.

Comment: Yeah I can see. His question says`A float variable results in correct output. However, on changing the data type to double result is NaN` > he wants to change the datatype from float to double and not double to double. You have just assigned a double variable to another double variable.

Comment: @AnishSharma, what do you mean by *he wants to change the datatype from float to double and not double to double*?  The OP changed the datatype of `a` to `double`, but didn't change the format specifier in `scanf()` and I pointed him to do just that.

Comment: he used `double c` to declare the variable. It is of type `double` and not `float`. How can you switch format specifiers?.

Comment: [sqrt()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/sqrt) returns a `double`.  Besides, where can you see that I have changed the datatype of `c`?  What are you talking about?

Comment: I mean you have declared `double a`. but he declared `float a`

Comment: Above you mentioned `double c` and now `double a`.  Please decide.  Besides, I think I already answered this question of why `double a`.  You might have to read the OP's question yet again to understand what he wants.  Thanks.

Comment: how about using `sqrtf()`, which accepts and returns `float` data type?

Comment: @user3078414, yes, but that is not OP's question.  He has mentioned specifically about changing the datatype to `double`.